# How to delete recycler view item from room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am using MVVM architecture model to create an app.I have recycler view in MainActivity and on click of a delete button in recycler view item it should be removed from room database.I know item can be removed within adapter class but as I am using MVVM model I want to carry out delete operation in Repository class.

This is my code below:

**UserDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void Insert(User... users);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers();

@Delete
void Delete(User... user);
}
```

**UserAdapter.java**

```
public class UserAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<User> userList;
Context context;

public UserAdapter(List<User> userList, Context context) {
    this.userList = userList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_row_layout,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final User users = userList.get(position);

    holder.row_name.setText(users.getName());
    holder.row_age.setText(users.getAge());

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView row_name,row_age;
    ImageView delete;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        row_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
        row_age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_age);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
      }
   }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

private Context context;
private UserDb userDb;
private LiveData<List<User>> listLiveData;

public UserRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    userDb = UserDb.getInstance(context);
    listLiveData = userDb.userDao().getRoomUsers();
}

public void getUserList(){

          Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
          ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

          Call<List<User>> userList = apiService.getUser();

          userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, final Response<List<User>> response) {

                  Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() throws Exception {

                              if(response.body() != null) {

                                  List<User> list = response.body();

                                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                                      String id = list.get(i).getId();
                                      String names = list.get(i).getName();
                                      String age = list.get(i).getAge();

                                          User user = new User(id,names,age);

                                          userDb.userDao().Insert(user);

                                   }
                                 }
                            }
                      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                                Toast.makeText(context,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });


              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(context,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });

}

public LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers(){

    return listLiveData;
  }
}
```

**UserViewModel.java**

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private UserRepository repo;
private LiveData<List<User>> listLiveData;

public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    repo = new UserRepository(application);
    listLiveData = repo.getRoomUsers();

}

public LiveData<List<User>> getListLiveData() {
    return listLiveData;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

UserRepository userRepository;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
UserViewModel userModel;
List<User> userList;
UserAdapter adapter;
ProgressBar prg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    prg = findViewById(R.id.prg);

    userRepository = new UserRepository(this);
    userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    userList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new UserAdapter(userList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    userModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<User> users) {

            prg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adapter.setUserList(users);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddUser.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    userRepository.getUserList();
 }
```

Someone please let me know how do I implement delete operation. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, initialize `UserViewModel` in your adapter class like how you did in `MainActivity`, then call delete function.

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             userModel.deleteItem(users);  
        }
    });
```

Add this function in `UserModel` class.

```
public void deleteItem(User user) = repo.deleteItem(user);
```

In `UserRepository` class, call `Delete` function.

```
public void deleteItem(User user) {
        userDb.userDao().Delete(user);
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to create instance of View model class in adapter class like this ``UserviewModel userModel = ViewModelProviders.of((Activity)context).get(UserViewModel.class);`` but it is showing under ``of()``.

Comment: wha you mean ??

Comment: I mean we need to create  an object of UserViewModel class in adapter class so in my above comment how do I get context of adapter class in ''Viewmodel Providers.of()''.

Comment: `UserviewModel userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(context).get(UserViewModel.class);`. What error you get?

Comment: When I am using context it is showing red line under and saying Cast parameter to android.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: But I am not using any fragment in my app it is purely  an activity class.

Comment: try this `(FragmentActivity) context`

Comment: Item is deleted from room database but still persists on server so how do I delete an item from both room as well as from server.

Comment: you need to call the delete url in `ApiService`.

Comment: UserviewModel userModel = ViewModelProviders((FragmentActivity)context).get(UserViewModel.class);

Answer (score 0):

Try to observe changes form the database with live data, whenever you perform anything, adding or deleting(in the database), in your observer refresh that data for the recycler view

Set a click listener to your Adapter

```
public interface OnListInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListInteraction(User user);
    }
```

In Adapter class

```
private final OnListInteractionListener mListener;

    public UserAdapter(List<User> users, OnListInteractionListener listener,Context context) {

        mListener = listener;
    }
```

and in view bind holder

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

mListener.onListInteraction(userList.get(position))
        }
    });
```

Implement that listener in your activity/fragment and from that, you can access Viewmodel and repo

Comment: My question is how do I implement delete operation.

Comment: That's what I told you, try to observe changes from DB if you want to keep delete in your DB

Comment: But I am trying to implement delete operation in my code on click of a button.

Comment: what's the issue then, if you are observing the changes and preparing the data for recycler view from the observer, then DbInstance.delete() will automatically tell the observer that, data has been changed.

Comment: For that how do I pass Id of an item from my adapter class to repository were I am carrying out all the operations.