# How to call ViewModel.delete from RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I want to call my ViewModel.delete (Room Database) method from my Recyclerview Adapter but it's not working. Any ideas?

I want to call the ViewModel in OnBindViewHolder like:
holder.binding.ivItemWalletDelete.setOnClickListener {
WalletViewModel...
}

but I get the error: on a null object

**RecyclerView Adapter (WalletListAdapter.kt)**

```
class WalletListAdapter:
        ListAdapter<Wallet, WalletListAdapter.ViewHolder>(WalletDiffCallback()){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemWalletsBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: Wallet) {
            binding.wallet = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ItemWalletsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class WalletDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Wallet>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Wallet, newItem: Wallet): Boolean {
        return oldItem.walletId == newItem.walletId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Wallet, newItem: Wallet): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

**ViewModel (WalletViewModel.kt)**

```
class WalletViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = WalletRepository(application)
    private val liveWalletList = repository.getLiveDataWallets()

    fun insert(wallet: Wallet){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insert(wallet)
        }
    }

    fun update(wallet: Wallet){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.update(wallet)
        }
    }

    fun delete(wallet: Wallet){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.delete(wallet)
        }
    }

    fun getWalletById(walletId: Long): Wallet? {
        var wallet: Wallet? = null
        viewModelScope.launch {
            wallet = repository.getWalletById(walletId)
        }
        return wallet
    }

    fun getAllWallets(): List<Wallet>? {
        var wallets: List<Wallet>? = null
        viewModelScope.launch {
            wallets = repository.getAllWallets()
        }
        return wallets
    }

    fun getLiveWalletList(): LiveData<List<Wallet>> = liveWalletList
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247644/how-to-delete-recycler-view-item-from-room-database else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252600/delete-item-from-recyclerview-on-button-click-kotlin-mvvm-firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of tackling this kind of problem would be to create a callback that would be passed into the adapter.

In your `WalletListAdapter` class pass in a callback that takes a `Wallet` object.

```kotlin
class WalletListAdapter(private val onDeleteCallback: (Wallet) -> Unit) {}
```

In your `ViewHolder` you can set an `OnClickListener` on each recycler view item and pass in the `Wallet` object to the callback function. That would look something like this:

```kotlin
binding.root.setOnClickListener { onDeleteCallback(item) }
```

Finally, the view (activity, fragment, etc) that initialized the `WalletListAdapter` would pass in a function that accepts a `Wallet` object. This is where you then call the `WalletViewModel`'s delete function.

```kotlin
class WalletListActivity: Activity() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var viewModel: WalletViewModel

  override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    // initialize the WalletListAdapter and pass in the callback
    val adapter = WalletListAdapter(::deleteWallet)

  }

  private fun deleteWallet(wallet: Wallet) {
    viewModel.delete(wallet)
  }

}
```

Note: You can first initialize the `WalletListAdapter` class with an empty constructor, then create a method to pass in the callback function from the view to the `WalletListAdapter` class. The point is to "propagate" the click event from the adapter back to the view, so the view can call the viewmodel's method.

Comment: thank you very much. It's working perfectly!!